# Remove NSWindowController from NSMutableArray when window is closed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsmutablearray, nswindowcontroller

I want to be able to create multiple instances of a window in a Cocoa application. Therefore I have created a NSWindowController and associated XIB. In my application delegate I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)newWindow:(id)sender
{
    MyWindowController *wc = [[MyWindowController alloc]
            initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
    [self.windowControllers addObject:wc];
    [wc showWindow:self];
}
```

I have to keep a pointer to the window controller somewhere, since ARC will otherwise dealloc it. I've found that a common solution is to add it to a mutable array. However, if the window is later closed the reference will still be in the array and therefore not deallocated.

What's the best way to remove the window controller from the array when the window is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use - `(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` instance method of `NSWindowDelegate`.

I could not find it in the documentation, but try using `(BOOL)windowWillClose:(id)sender` first.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/UsingWindowNotDel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000239-BAJBCBBF).

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't that mean that the window controller will be deallocated by ARC in the middle of windowWillClose:?

Comment: I don't use ARC yet, but I've read about it. I think that if you have a strong reference to the window controller then it is up to you deallocate it.

Comment: After investigating it a bit further it looks like the window controller is retained while windowShouldClose: is called, so it's OK to remove it from the array from there.