# Removing reference to NSWindowController from AppDelegate on windowWillClose causes crash

Tags: macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following method in my `GameWindowController` (subclass of `NSWindowController`):

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AppDelegate *delegate = [NSApp delegate];
    [delegate removeGameWindowController:self];
}
```

The code for removeGameWindowController in AppDelegate is:

```
- (void)removeGameWindowController:(GameWindowController*)controller {
    [self.controllers removeObject:controller];
}
```

`self.controllers` is an NSMutableArray with all my `GameWindowControllers`.

The above code seems to have a race condition. It will randomly crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I close windows, almost every time if I close all windows at once.

My guess is that ARC is deallocating the window controller before or as `removeGameWindowController:` returns, leaving the window with a dangling pointer to the controller. I have tried adding `controller.window.windowController = nil;` to no avail.

For some reason, using the `(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` delegate method instead as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11782844/344544 works, but is not an acceptable solution as it is not called upon quit.

How can I reliably remove my window controllers from the array of controllers after each window has closed? Is there some other delegate method which gets called or some NSNotification I can subscribe to which fire after a window has finished closing?

Answer (score 0):

After lengthy investigation and step by step running in the debugger I figured out the source of the problem and a possible solution.

The window controller was indeed being released at some point after the end of `removeGameWindowController:` along with all its strong references which include the `NSWindow`. If the window was released before the stack had unwound back to the `close` call on the window itself, the program would crash while finishing the that function as `self` in this particular case is a dangling pointer.

I was unable to find a way to get notified after a window had closed, however it is likely such an approach would have had the exact same problem.

In order to ensure no reference to the window was left anywhere on the stack I queued the removal of the window controller from the array to happen as a subsequent event on the runloop:

```
- (void)removeGameWindowController:(GameWindowController*)controller {
    [self.controllers performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeObject:) withObject:controller waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: Using a variant of `performSelector` is rarely the right approach.  Did you try creating a strong reference to the window on the stack in the function where `close` is called?  That will prevent the window from being deallocated early.

Comment: I have no control over the method where close is called from, it is called by the default close menu bar items in the default menu bar.